# Determine average for different years in one dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataset with 44522 rows which contains information about different years. I need to calculate an average of the values for every year with a nested loop. i have the following code:

```
m= len(inf)
nrow, ncol = inf.shape
print(nrow, ncol)

years = [2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016]

total = 0
index = None

for i in range(nrow):
     year = inf.iloc[i, 0].year
     data = inf.max_wave_height[i]
     #print(year)

     for j in range(len(years)):
         date = years[j]
         #print(date)

         if year == date:
             total = total + data
             avg = total/(i+1)
             index = i
         else: break
```

This code calculates only for 1 year and stops after that. That's not what i want to. Can somebody help me to solve this problem?

Comment: What is the frequency of your time series data?

Comment: It is hard to say that, because it contains too much information. İt gives values per hour for every day for the whole year. And this for multiple years.

Comment: For example, the first 4510 rows contain information about 2020 en the next 8000 rows 2011 etc

Answer (score 1):

change `break` to `continue` :)

you quit the for-loop as soon as the `if` evaluates to False, which is for the first time that `date=2011`

Comment: thanks for your reaction,
but how do i print the calculated value per year then?

Comment: Oh, sorry it took so long, I didn't return to the page lately ... well, have you tried `print(avg)` inside the inner `for`-loop, just after you calculate it?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give you a meaningful answer without seeing your data frame. But in general, in this type of situation the best solution is to use Pandas [resample()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) function.

I will demonstrate a `resample` solution, then you could apply it to your own data frame.

In this first part, I will construct a data frame, *just for the demo*, using the time series data for the years you listed in your question:

```
years = pd.date_range('1/1/2010', '12/31/2016', freq='D')
print(years)
DatetimeIndex(['2010-01-01', '2010-01-02', '2010-01-03', '2010-01-04',
               '2010-01-05', '2010-01-06', '2010-01-07', '2010-01-08',
               '2010-01-09', '2010-01-10',
               ...
               '2016-12-22', '2016-12-23', '2016-12-24', '2016-12-25',
               '2016-12-26', '2016-12-27', '2016-12-28', '2016-12-29',
               '2016-12-30', '2016-12-31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=2557, freq='D')

np.random.seed(seed=1111)
data = np.random.randint(1, high=100, size=len(years))
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': years, 'col2': data})
print(df.head(10))
  col1          col2
0 2010-01-01    29
1 2010-01-02    56
2 2010-01-03    82
3 2010-01-04    13
4 2010-01-05    35
5 2010-01-06    53
6 2010-01-07    25
7 2010-01-08    23
8 2010-01-09    21
9 2010-01-10    12
```

Then, the actual solution, to find the mean for each year is very simple using `resample()`.

```
df = df.set_index('col1')
annual_mean = pd.DataFrame()
annual_mean['Anual Mean'] = df.col2.resample('AS').mean()
print(annual_mean)
             Anual Mean
col1                  
2010-01-01   48.723288
2011-01-01   48.931507
2012-01-01   49.237705
2013-01-01   50.386301
2014-01-01   49.715068
2015-01-01   49.753425
2016-01-01   47.346995
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. This could work, but ı have to do it with a nested loop. The only problem that i have now is to print the calculated average value for every year

Comment: @OzgeKilic I am curious, why you have to use a "nested loop"?

Comment: This is an assignment that I have to do and I really have to do it with a nested loop, otherwise I wont pass. Iknow that they are easier ways to solve this, but i just have no choice.